# Crop an image to exact measurements

Tags: graphics, xetex, document-classes, includegraphics

I know that with `\includegraphics` there is the option to trim images, but this is only practical for images I know the size of, so I can trim them the way it fits perfectly for the given image.

Assuming I want to add a random image to my document (I am using XeLaTex). I want to resize it to exact measurements - say 250x300px - without knowing the actual size of the image (but assuming it is at least as big as these measurements).

Is there a package for an automatical cropping of images like described above?

**EDIT:** For further visualization, I will add a little sketch of what I aim to achieve.

Assume I have a document in which I want to place an image with specific height AND width (my placeholder). Now I want to add the image with the palm trees that obviously has a size not fitting to the placeholder.

[image: 1]

What I want is the image to be cropped somewhere (not necessarily beautifully) to fit the given size:

[image: 2]

In reality, the given images will be actually of a similar size as the placeholder, so a "random" cropping wouldn't be that ugly. But it is necessary for my design's sake that every picture fulfils the given height and width properties exactly.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to just shrink a large image?  I don't like to crop images at "random" places, only where I know the image subject won't be compromised.  The `graphicx` package provides quite a few methods for resizing.

Comment: I also do not understand the question. You do not want `\includegraphics[width=...,height=..]{graphics}`. Is that correct? If so, why, i.e. what is wrong with this option?

Comment: @barbara beeton In my case, I actually want to "crop images at 'random' places", because I am currently writing a class file where the user should be able to drop any picture (preferably in a similar size), so any excess should be cut away automatically. When using [width=..., height=...] the image isn't cropped but just resized. I instead want it to be actually cropped to these given width and height.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I added an sketch of what I want to achieve and why! Hope this will explain my question better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\picdims[...]{<x-dim>}{<ydim>}{<image-file>}` is provided, where the user can specify the x and y dimensions of the cropped image.  Cropping is done symmetrically.

First, I store a copy of the uncropped image in the temporary `\box0`. This allows me to establish its total width `\wd0` and height `\ht0`.  The desired x,y image dimensions are provided by the user in `#2` and `#3`.  Therefore, a total of `\wd0-#2` must be horizontally clipped and `\ht0-#3` must be vertically clipped to achieve the final clipped dimension. I cut these dimensions in half via `.5\dimexpr...\relax` and apply those clipping amounts symmetrically to the left/right and the top/bottom respectively.  This clipping is done via `\clipbox` in which the `<left bottom right  top>` clipping amounts are provided as a space-separated list in the first argument to the `\clipbox`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,trimclip}
\newcommand\picdims[4][]{%
  \setbox0=\hbox{\includegraphics[#1]{#4}}%
  \clipbox{.5\dimexpr\wd0-#2\relax{} %
           .5\dimexpr\ht0-#3\relax{} %
           .5\dimexpr\wd0-#2\relax{} %
           .5\dimexpr\ht0-#3\relax}{\includegraphics[#1]{#4}}}
\parskip 1ex
\begin{document}
\includegraphics[width=2in]{example-image}\par
\picdims[width=2in]{1in}{1in}{example-image}\par
\picdims[width=2in]{1.5in}{1in}{example-image}\par
\picdims[width=2in]{1in}{.5in}{example-image}\par
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This worked perfectly. Would you like to explain a bit of what exactly you did there? Especially in the ```\clipbox``` part?

Comment: @TiMauzi I have added some explanation.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to the already mentioned way, I found out a similar approach which only uses graphicx without trimclip. It also starts off with a `\box0` but uses the `trim` option of `includegraphics`. The rest is similar to Steven B. Segletes' solution before:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand\picdims[4][]{%
    \setbox0=\hbox{\includegraphics[#1]{#4}}%
    \includegraphics[trim={.5\dimexpr\wd0-#2\relax{},
    .5\dimexpr\ht0-#3\relax{},
    .5\dimexpr\wd0-#2\relax{},
    .5\dimexpr\ht0-#3\relax{}},
    clip,#1]{#4}%
}
```